# Firestore Community Connector for Google Data Studio is not working

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, looker-studio

After following the instructions on https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/tree/master/firestore I keep running into the following error after Authorization:

Community Connector Error
There was an error caused by the community connector. Please report the issue to the provider of this community connector if this issue persists.

Connector details
There was an error caused by this connector.

Any advice as to what I might be missing would be great.